# python module not found if sudo or user: root

Tags: python, bash

When I want to import a module into Python under the current user the import works OK. But when I want to import the same module as a root user, all of the sudden the module is not found.

Here is the the proof:

```
root@raspberrypi:/home/pi/Programs# whoami
root
root@raspberrypi:/home/pi/Programs# python3
Python 3.7.3 (default, Apr  3 2019, 05:39:12) 
[GCC 8.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import paho.mqtt.client as paho
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'paho'
>>> 
root@raspberrypi:/home/pi/Programs# su pi
pi@raspberrypi:~/Programs $ python3
Python 3.7.3 (default, Apr  3 2019, 05:39:12) 
[GCC 8.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import paho.mqtt.client as paho
>>> 
pi@raspberrypi:~/Programs $
```

I have already tried to modify the `.bashrc` as root by adding the `PYTHONPATH` to the module, but without success. What am I missing?

This is the output as a regular user:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/Programs $ whoami
pi
pi@raspberrypi:~/Programs $ python3 -c 'import sys; print(sys.path)'
['', '/home/pi/Programs', '/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/Adafruit_PCA9685', '/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/Adafruit_GPIO', '/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/paho', '/home/pi/Programs/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/paho', '/usr/lib/python37.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.7', '/usr/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload', '/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages', '/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages', '/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/rpi_ws281x-1.0.0-py3.7-linux-armv7l.egg', '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages']
```

And this is the output as root:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/Programs $ su
root@raspberrypi:/home/pi/Programs# python3 -c 'import sys; print(sys.path)'
['', '/home/pi/Programs', '/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/Adafruit_PCA9685', '/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/Adafruit_GPIO', '/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/paho', '/home/pi/Programs/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/paho', '/usr/lib/python37.zip', '/usr/lib/python3.7', '/usr/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages', '/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/rpi_ws281x-1.0.0-py3.7-linux-armv7l.egg', '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages']
```

It seems in both versions path to `paho` is the same !???

Comment: Try to run `python -c 'import sys; print(sys.path)'` with and without root and check the difference.

Comment: It looks like you've installed `paho` using `--user` in `pip`.

Comment: how did you install `paho`?

Comment: not a  pro on this topic but the reason can be `umask` . Check the details here https://www.linuxnix.com/umask-define-linuxunix/

Comment: I did install paho with command: "pip3 install paho-mqtt"

Comment: did you try to use `sudo`when you install `sudo pip3 install paho-mqtt` ?

Comment: Thank you furas
"sudo pip3 install paho-mqtt" is the solution to my problem ! This is saving my day!!